# Linker error undefined reference to `timer_getoverrun' (-lrt linker option doesn't work)

Tags: gcc, time, timer, cygwin

I am trying to compile example code from [timer_create()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) Linux>man_page. using following command line:

> gcc example.c -o example -lrt

Nevertheless, I have linker error:

> undefined reference to `timer_getoverrun'

Why -lrt couldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry - timer_getoverrun() isn't implemented under Cygwin.

Comment: It depends.  Cygwin tries to implement POSIX (and in particular Linux) as much as possible, but it's limited by the underlying Windows kernel.  The timer_getoverrun() function is part of the POSIX real-time extension, so is not even guaranteed to be present even on otherwise POSIX platforms.  I've worked with a POSIX OS (not Cygwin) that had all the timer_* functions **except** for timer_getoverrun().

Comment: Thank you. I remove this function and rearranged code. It works.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  If you're happy with the answer, please accept it.